# Unable to install wordpress theme - ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, console

I recently created an ubuntu virtual server(EC2) on Amazon Web Services, then installed wordpress through console *apt-get install wordpress* , before that I installed, apache, php and mysql. The website is running, but the problem is that I can't install wordpress themes, I get this message:

*Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/twentysixteen.1.1.zip…
Unpacking the package…
Could not create directory.*

I already give the right permissions to these folders :
usr/share/wordpress/wp-content,
usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/themes,
usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins,
usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/languages

And added this line:
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
 to **usr/share/wordpress/wp-config.php**
at the end.

I don't know what else to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently figure out how to fix it, I edited this file:
/etc/wordpress/config-mydomain.com.php

And found this line:
define('WP-CONTENT-DIR','srv/www/wp-content/localhost');

This must be replaced by:
define('WP-CONTENT-DIR','var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content');

This often happen when you use this file to create your database and setup your files in ubuntu: usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql

And then you can install themes without problems, but you must give aproppiate permissions to the folders wp-content, themes, etc. after fix this!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the content directory
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/wordpress/wp-content');